# G++ fails to compile Win7, 64bit (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw-w64

G++ fails to compile simple "Hello World" code.
Platform details are in the Title
I have tried to run from both VS Code ("insiders" version 1.26.0), and from the Windows command-line /terminal.
Neither route will return an *.exe file
This is the C++ code. VSCode Intellisense doesn't show any errors (C++17)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Fresh New World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At the Windows command line (terminal) I've used the command

```
g++ -o FreshWorld.exe FreshWorld.cpp
```

This command does **not** return an error, nor does it return the desired *.exe file (I've even resorted to SEARCHing all the folders)
Running this in VSCode (1.26.0) also does not return an error.
I had run this code in the previous stable release (pre- "June 2018") VS Code, and it compiled properly. The problems started immediately after the update to Jn2018. I've worked with VS Code developers (that's why I'm running the "insiders" version) but, as we now know, the problem also exists at the command-line (terminal) so not confined to VS Code.
Any ideas??????
I am entire newbie to C++, MinGW, and to VS Code so this has become an insurmountable hurdle to further experimentation and learning!

Comment: Reinstall your compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things could be causing this:

1. Antivirus: it could be intercepting the gcc executable (they tend to dislike other compilers due to the way a compiler generates executable code etc.). Try disabling the antivirus and test again.
2. Your MinGW(-w64) installation is broken. Try reinstalling. Where are you getting your GCC? I strongly suggest using something like the official MinGW-builds for MinGW-w64 [here](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds) or a package management system such as [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/).
3. Wrong environment settings. Your provide little details of how and what you are doing (how are you starting the command prompt interpreter, how is your PATH set up, etc.).

Without more details, I can't determine what is going wrong for you. Please edit your question to provide these details.

Comment: Per your suggestion...I tried to disable the antivirus and running g++ through VS Code.....I watched the File Explorer side panel, and a file "a.exe" appeared for less than one half of a second...a mere blip. Then it was gone, and a persistent *.exe file was not generated.

Comment: I am using Win7 64 bit. But my MinGW is from the official MinGW site and mirrors and it is not the product of the parallel project, MinGW-w64. I did not get error messages during the initial installation, nor do I get 32 bit / 64 bit incompatibility issues when running. Comments ??

Comment: Try MinGW-w64 anyway. Chances just might be your problem magically goes away. The old MinGW has gone stale quite a while ago. All big players (Qt, Linux distributions, and basically anyone who wants 64-bit software (who doesn’t in 2018?) have switched. Something is still moving/deleting your executable though. I can’t tell you what that is, but to me it sounds like antivirus software. Are you sure all of it is completely disabled?

Comment: New twist: I have  "System Mechanic" (iolo.com) installed on my computer and an update was installed today. After your suggestion, I went to my antivirus (MS Security Essentials), and turned off every option I could. I then disconnected from the 'net to lower my risk. Then I ran VS Code, and it generated the a.exe.

Comment: Obviously, I don't want to run without antivirus. So, I deleted the a.exe file and Built my code after incrementally re-activating features from MS Security Essentials. The overall result was, I could reactivate ALL features of the AV software and VS Code still generated the a.exe file.......From this, I conclude that there was some feature of Iolo's SYSTEM MECHANIC that was blocking the compilation. For the record, the AV option of the (now updated /replaced) SysMechanic was NOT activated, nor is the AV option of the new SysMechanic running now.

Comment: A hiccup remains. My default BUILD task (task.json) compiles, but it doesn't terminate....it passes to the LAUNCH.JSON and normally the Terminal Window should indicate that it 'will be reused.....press any key to close...'. That no longer happens, and it doesn't allow me the use of the Powershell to execute the a.exe file it has created. Ideas?? Comments??